# Weird issue with USB 3.0 port and keyboard

Tags: windows-7, drivers, keyboard, usb-3, signal

I bought a new computer and installed Windows 7.

As I see and understand, I have USB 3.0 drivers already installed. When I tried to install from Intel, I got a message that I already have newer drivers installed.

I have in my computer case:

- One front USB 3.0 port
- Two back USB 3.0 ports

1. When I connect my USB flash drive (USB 3.0) to the front port, it says "USB 3.0 This device can perform faster. This USB Mass Storage Device can transfer information faster if you connect it to a Super-Speed USB 3.0 port". Why? It is a 3.0 port.
2. The second problem is when I connect the USB flash drive (without even transfer files) to the back ports, it for some reason makes the keyboard reception weaker and then the keyboard works only when I get closer. When I pull out the USB drive it works like magic from far away.

Comment: The front port may not be USB 3.0 capable or it may be connected to the incorrect motherboard header. - Was the computer pre-built? In regards to the second problem, the usb receivers for mice and keyboards are very weak in terms of signal strength. The usb drive may just be acting as a shield blocking or messing with the signal. I would recommend plugging your wireless device's receiver to a port on the front of your pc or to a separate adapter that can be placed to directly face your keyboard.

Comment: the computer is pre-bulit by the store i bought it from , maybe they connected that incorrect? this is big company..

Comment: Did they say that it was a USB 3.0 port?  or is it indicated by a blue color port on the front? It may just be a standard 2.0 port. If it is a blue 3.0 port, then you need to see if the cable is connected to a 3.0 motherboard header (different from the old 2.0 header).  I am not sure how comfortable you are with taking the side panel off the PC, but you may need to (in order the follow the cable). If it is,  in fact, connected to a 3.0 port,  then it is a driver issue.  If not,  then it needs to be connected to a 3.0 port (if possible).